# Why does postinst script for tweak app cause app icon dispear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak, cydia-substrate

I make a tweak app works inside `backboardd`, so `backboardd` has to be restarted after the tweak is installed.I used the script below in `DEBIAN`'s `postinst` to restart backboardd.
It works right for me, but lead to a new problem: it respring automatically at the end of the installation without the "Restart SpringBoard" button click in `Cydia`, and for that, there don't show the app icon on the home screen except you reboot the device entirely.What can I do for that?

```
#!/bin/sh

launchctl stop com.apple.backboardd
```

Comment: This is explained in the answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21569039/119114).  `uicache` is the command to cause new apps' icons to appear, without a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cydia does kill backboardd and you don't have to do it yourself.

http://gitweb.saurik.com/cydia.git/blob/HEAD:/MobileCydia.mm#l5329

Comment: I've found it does this, you know everything :)